# How to get GTK3 checkboxes in certain themes?

Tags: 11.10, themes, xfce, gtk3

Xubuntu 11.10 introduces some GTK3 applications which don't play well with GTK2 themed apps. Base GTK3 theme is quite ugly, so I tried a couple of themes with both gtk2/3 components like "Elegant Brit" or "Evolve". I noticed that the **checkboxes** are missing in quite a lot of these themes. One only sees a very slight hover effect over the checkable line, but no box. The check-mark is visible though.

For example: Audacious with Elegant Brit theme:

[image]

Is there an easy way (a simple line in some configfile) to get the checkboxes back? Maybe point me to a good guide to GTK themeing?

Is there a program to switch GTK3 themes (NOT gnome-tweak-tool, which grabs the whole gnome-shell as dependency)?

Answer (score 2):

> "Is there a program to switch GTK3 themes (NOT gnome-tweak-tool, which
>   grabs the whole gnome-shell as dependency)?"

I use Lubuntu 11.10. To set a GTK3 theme :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/theme/GTK3Theme/gtk-3.0 ~/.config/gtk-3.0
```

Comment: this works indeed, but so would copying the gtk-3.0 folder into currently used folder of the gtk2 theme.

Answer (score 0):

*NOT gnome-tweak-tool, which grabs the whole gnome-shell as dependency*

FALSE:

*sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool --no-install-recommends*

Comment: thx, have to try that some time